# <generator object in_a_row at 0x0xxxxxxx>

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

Any help is very aprreciated. I try to understand Iterable Object here:

Here I have to define a function in_a_row, which is passed an integer argument (call it n) and iterable argument. This function returns a set of those values in the iterable that occur n times in a row: in_a_row(2,[4,4,2,6,6,9,6,7,7,3,2,2]) returns {2, 4, 6, 7}. If the iterable does not contain at least n values, return an empty set. Raise an AssertionError if n is not at least 2.

I came up with the code:

```
def in_a_row(n,iterable):
    assert n>=2, 'n has to at least 2'

    result = set()
    while any(iterable):
        copy = iter(iterable)
        for i in copy:
            print(i)
            if i == next(iterable):
                result.add(i)
        yield result
```

But when I test with test cases:

```
print('Testing in_a_row')
    print(in_a_row(2,[4,4,2,6,6,9,6,7,7,3,2,2]))
    print(in_a_row(3,[5,3,7,7,7,2,3,8,5,4,4,4,6]))
    print(in_a_row(4,[5,5,5]))
    for i in range(5,1,-1):
        print('for',i,'=',in_a_row(i,map(lambda x : x.rstrip(),open('in_a_row.txt'))))
```

I got all weirds result Iterable Object: (+_+")?!

```
Testing in_a_row
<generator object in_a_row at 0x02871AF8>
<generator object in_a_row at 0x02871AF8>
<generator object in_a_row at 0x02871AF8>
for 5 = <generator object in_a_row at 0x028804B8>
for 4 = <generator object in_a_row at 0x028804B8>
for 3 = <generator object in_a_row at 0x028804B8>
for 2 = <generator object in_a_row at 0x028804B8>
```

Suppose to be retrun the set() of numbers?!

```
{4,6,7,2}
{7,4}
{}
{'l', 'i'}
{'l', 'i', 'c'}
{'l', 'm', 'i', 'f', 'c', 'x', 'z'}
```

Cannot use any buit-in function python like "itertools", only while loop + iter + next :(

Comment: Aside: `while any(iterable)` checks to see whether any value is truthlike; for example, if `iterable == [0,0,0]`, `any(iterable)` will be False and so the loop won't be entered.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You're yielding an item each time, so if you want to materialise them in a `set`, you'd have to use `set`, eg:

```
print(set(in_a_row(2,[4,4,2,6,6,9,6,7,7,3,2,2])))
      ^^^
```

However, you can massively simplify your function using `itertools.groupby` and return a `set` to start with:

```
from itertools import groupby
def in_a_row(n, iterable):
    return {k for k, g in groupby(iterable) if len(list(g)) >= n}
```

If you wanted to stick to yield a value at a time, and put them in a `set` later, then you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby
def in_a_row(n, iterable):
    yield from (k for k, g in groupby(iterable) if len(list(g)) >= n)
```

Comment: Thank for the solution, but in this case I cannot use the any buit-in function python like "itertools" :(

Comment: @TrungNguyen well, stick with your custom function and just use `set(...)` on it then...

Comment: CAn u show me? I'm stuck on how to use set(...) on it?! :(

Comment: @TrungNguyen the first line of code I've posted is an example of how to change your first print statement... try that - that'll make a `set` out of the results of your generator... (whether those are correct or not is down to you)

Comment: I cannot change the test_case that'y I'm stuck :(

Comment: @TrungNguyen if your function is meant to return a `set`, then you don't want to be yielding results and can't use a generator then... I think you need to clarify your exact requirements...